# Pass --nogpgcheck to yum via puppet

Tags: puppet, yum, options

How would one get a `--nogpgcheck` option to yum via puppet? I've tried

```
package { 'unsigned-package':
  ensure          => latest,
  install_options => ['--nogpgcheck'],
}
```

and

```
package { 'unsigned-package':
  ensure          => latest,
  install_options => ['nogpgcheck'],
}
```

but looking at the output from an agent run, yum isn't getting that option.

As an aside (and maybe the reason it's not working for me), how do I verify my puppet has the **install_options** feature?

I'm running puppet 3.3.0-rc2.

Comment: About to break down a [gpg sign the rpms](http://systembash.com/content/simple-guide-to-signing-rpms-with-fpm/). I'd rather do that than come up with the ruby code to extend puppet, or some exec-based workaround in the manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that with puppet 3.7.1 passing 'install_options' to the yum provider works. I was able to successfully pass '--nogpgcheck' using it. Just update your puppet now.

Comment: Nice, they must have gotten it in there on a later rev. I'll take your word for it, since I haven't done much puppet work lately.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to answer my second question, and it looks like **install_options** is not implemented for yum on 3.3.0-rc2.

```
$ grep -ro install_options /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/package/ | sort | uniq
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/package/msi.rb:install_options
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/package/sun.rb:install_options
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/package/windows.rb:install_options
```

And an answer to the real question, since this is a custom repository, the trick was to disable gpg checks. This can be done in the instantiation of the [puppet *yumrepo* type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#yumrepo), as in

```
yumrepo { 'customrepo':
  gpgcheck => 0,
}
```

Another option, as stated in my comment beneath the question would be to gpg sign the packages.

Answer (score 0):

As of puppet 3.4.0

```
 class pkgoptions {

        package { 'strace':
          ensure          => 'installed',
          provider        => 'yum',
          install_options => [ '--noplugins', '--enablerepo=fedora' ],
          # or install_options => [ '-t', 'squeeze-backports' ], for Debian backports
        }

      }
```

Reference: http://www.unixdaemon.net/tools/puppet/puppet-package-install-options.html

Comment: This is a patch and is not available in the regular package, I'm running 3.5.1 and install_options still doesn't work for yum. See quickshiftin's answer